# Why promises return "undefined" Nodejs Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, fetch

i have this problems, when i try to create a Promises, in the main function, returns "undefined"
here is the code

```
export const pdfDownload = async ({ itemData }) => {
    let today = new Date();
    const { client_number, document_date, document_number, document_url, dx } = itemData
    let url = document_url
    let path = "./files/Downloads/" + dx + "/" + today.getDate() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getFullYear() + "/"
        + client_number + "-" + document_date + "-" + today.getDate() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getFullYear() + "-" + document_number + ".pdf";
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(path);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        res.body.pipe(fileStream);
        res.body.on("error", reject);
        fileStream.on("finish", resolve);
    })

}
const asdf = async () => {
  const itemData = {
    client_number: "holaaaa",
    document_date: 'asdf',
    document_number: 3,
    document_url: "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",
    dx: "test"
  }
  console.log(await pdfDownload({ itemData }))

}
asdf();
```

in asdf function, should recibe the result of the promise from pdfDownload right?
in the part "console.log(await pdfDownload({ itemData }))" is where i get "undefined"

Comment: `asdf()` does not explicitly return anything, likely hence the `undefined` you're seeing. Can you elaborate as to how this deviates from your expectation?

Comment: `finish` event does not have any parameters so `resolve` will be called with `undefined`

Comment: i modified thhe explanations, sorry for the inconvenients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two functions here that return a promise, `pdfDownload()` and `asdf()`.  Both of those function resolve their promise with no resolved value, thus an `undefined` resolved value.

`pdfDownload()` gets its promise resolved from this line:

```
fileStream.on("finish", resolve);
```

But, when the `finish` event is emitted, it has no arguments, thus `resolve()` will be called with no arguments so that promise will be resovled with `undefined` as the resolved value.

`asdf()` gets its promise from the `async` declaration so we look to see what the function returns because that return value will become the resolved value of the promise that the `async` function returns.  But, there is no explicit `return` statement so the return value is `undefined` and thus the promise that `asdf()` returns also resolves to an `undefined` value.

It's not clear what values you want these promises to resolve with.  You can set a resolved value in `pdfDownload()` by changing this:

```
fileStream.on("finish", resolve);
```

to this:

```
fileStream.on("finish", () => {
    resolve("all done");
});
```

And, you can set a resolved value in `asdf()`, by adding an explicit return value:

```
const asdf = async () => {
  const itemData = {
    client_number: "holaaaa",
    document_date: 'asdf',
    document_number: 3,
    document_url: "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",
    dx: "test"
  }
  let result = await pdfDownload({ itemData });
  console.log(result);
  return result;    
}

asdf().then(result => {
   console.log(`Got result = ${result}`);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: thanks you, now is working!, before a was trying 
"fileStream.on("finish" ,resolve("Download success")); but it keep throw error, but the way you show me works perfect!